# How can I make elements show up in a dropdown menu from a firestore database when a certain date is selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm working on a booking system project and I have a form that the user can fill out, with a date picker using react-datepicker and a dropdown menu with times that the users can select from. These times are fetched from a firestore database. The times collection looks like this: [times collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCg24.jpg). I open up the bookings slots for the next 2 weeks, but I want to render the available times from the arrays in each document when that specific date is selected in the react-datepicker component here is my code but it doesn't work, when I select a date, no times for that date show up whereas I want the times from the array from that date to show up. Here is my code:

```
  function GThirtyminsp() {
  // Form values
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [team, setTeam] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [time, setTime] = useState("");

  // To show times on screen
  const [times, setTimes] = useState([]);

  const timesRef = collection(db, "30min-goalie-semiprivate-times");
  const formRef = collection(db, "30min-goalie-semiprivate");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (date) {
        const timeData = await query(
          timesRef,
          where("date", "==", date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)),
          orderBy("time", "asc")
        );
        if (timeData.docs) {
          const times = timeData.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().times);
          setTimes(times);
        }
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [timesRef, date]);

  const createBooking = async () => {
    await addDoc(formRef, {
      name: name,
      date: date,
      email: email,
      number: number,
      team: team,
      age: age,
      time: time,
    });
  };

  const addTimesForNextThreeWeeks = async () => {
    // Get current date
    let currentDate = new Date();

    // Check if current day is Monday
    if (currentDate.getDay() === 1) {
      // Set times to generate
      const times = ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"];

      // Generate times for next three weeks
      for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        // Format date as string
        const formattedDate = currentDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

        // Add the times for this date to the database
        await addDoc(timesRef, {
          date: formattedDate,
          times: times,
        });

        // Increment current date by 1 day
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    addTimesForNextThreeWeeks();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    createBooking();

    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setDate(null);
    setNumber("");
    setTeam("");
    setTime(null);
    setAge("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 class="text-3xl w-full text-center pt-10 font-bold">
        Book 30min Semi-Private Goalie Clinic
      </h1>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} class="flex flex-col pt-10 w-3/4">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="number"
            placeholder="Phone Number"
            value={number}
            onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="team"
            placeholder="Team Name"
            value={team}
            onChange={(e) => setTeam(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="age"
            placeholder="Age"
            value={age}
            onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <h2 class="text-center text-xl py-5 font-bold">
            Pick a Date and Time
          </h2>
          <div class="pb-10">
            <DatePicker
              className="border-2 p-3 w-full border-gray rounded-lg"
              selected={date}
              onChange={(date) => setDate(date)}
              placeholderText="Select a Date"
            />
            <div class="pt-10">
              <Select
                options={times}
                placeholder="Time"
                onChange={(e) => setTime(e.value)}
                value={time}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <button
            type="submit"
            class="bg-accent text-white font-semibold p-3 rounded-full"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GThirtyminsp;
```

Comment: Could you show a console.log of timeData, so that we can debug? You could model your database a little better, these hours could be saved in an array instead of an object.

Comment: @GabrielNexT check the edited version^ i changed up the times to fi them in an array but I am still having the same problem. I think its because when I console.log(timeData), nothing is showing up in the console, I think thats the problem but I dont know what Im doing wrong

Comment: What would be nothing in this case, null?

Comment: @GabrielNexT no its just giving an empty array

Comment: Without the where the query also does not return any documents?

Comment: @GabrielNexT the query returns the date string but it doesnt return the times array. Do you have discord or anything? if you can help me with this, I have something for you in return

Comment: @GabrielNexT ??